# Extra toolbar in content in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

How to add simple tool bar in silverstripe in content like heading h1,h2 etc. I want to add a simple css class there.?
Any help is accepted. Thank you

Comment: hard to tell what's being asked here. you're talking about the rendered template output? what kind of 'toolbar'? what element to add a css class to?

Comment: If you want to add a class selector to styles dropdown on the CMS TinyMCE WYSIWYG  editor, this has a nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141209/silverstripe-adding-styles-to-styles-drop-down-menu-on-editor

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to configure the TineMCE HTMLEditorfield have a look at the [tinytidy module](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy). You'll have to copy the configuration example to your `mysite/_config.php` to make it working.